# Dimensional model combine or split dimension

Tags: business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I am building a DWH with reporting end goal. For one dimension i'm unsure wether i should put the hierarchie in one dimension table or if it's more correct to split. We start from the Employee dimension.

How a drill-down in a report should be done from business line 'people's' view: Business Line - Discipline - Employee

How the drill-down in a report should be done from regional people's view: Cluster - Office - Employee

BL, Discipline, Cluster, Office are all derived from the Employee, and each employee has all 4.
My idea was to put this hierarchie fully like this in one dimension table:
Business Line - Discipline - Cluster - Office - Employee and to just define in the front-end tool 2 views on the hierarchie that can be chosen by the user. The 2 views are coming from the same dimension table but the user won't know. This makes me need only one join between my facts & this dimension.

Now my collegue is from the idea that we should make 2 dimension tables specifically filled and designed for each possible hierarchie, in this case, 2. Exactly as defined above, he would make the tables exactly as the end user will want to use it:

Table 1: Business Line - Discipline - Employee

Table 2: Cluster - Office - Employee

And accordingly, have 2 integer columns in the fact tables to link to these 2 dimensions. The motivation would be the manageability.

The fact tables granularity for the Emp dimension(s) is the Emp ID.

Finally, my question is which of the 2 ways would be more according to "BI rules and regulations". We are +- familiar with Kimball.

Comment: It's totally normal to store multiple alternate hierarchies in one dimension. Having two dimension tables is _less_ manageable. You'd end up with two sets of surrogate keys etc. In fact it makes no sense to split two alternate hierarchies into two tables. Look up a 'junk dimension' - there is absolutely nothing wrong with mixing many things into a single dimension, let alone a couple of alternate hierarchies. Note that the end user never sees your database - you always have some kind of tool in the middle. If they _were_ to see and you wanted to split it out you would use a view.

Comment: and why would a person want to have to think about what table to join to for a certain hierarchy? One of the advantages of a star schema is that it's simple and doesn't have too many tables and joins. So don't complicate it by adding another table and another join if it is not necessary. Further to this a lot of dimensions have a lot more than two alternate hierarchies. We just don't create a table per hierarchy.